# Inconsistencies found in OpenID Provider's HTTP Headers. Which one is the most secure that I should imitate in my STS, and Relying Party?

Tags: authentication, tls, webserver, http, threat-mitigation

I'm comparing the HTTP headers of the various providers (LiveID, Google, Yahoo, etc) and notice a broad inconsistency in implementation on the sign in page, sign out page, and subsequent pages.

> What headers should I set/ignore, and what is the correct value to use in the following scenarios:
>
> - SignIn
> - General usage ([HTTPS only](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7790/396) site, or regular HTTP)
> - SignOut

Here are a list of headers that I've noticed and the differences among them.  I'm sure that each company had smart people implement or omit certain headers for a reason; I just can't tell which provider has the best implementation.

My bet is that each provider has something the others can learn from.

**Expires:**

- LiveID sets the Expires header to exactly one minute prior to the current time
- Google and MyOpenID has the Expires header equal to the current time
- Yahoo Expires at Thu, 05 Jan 1995 22:00:00 GMT
- Verisign PIP Expires at Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
- Facebook Expires Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
- ADFSv2 -1
- Not present in Azure ACS

**Cache Control:**

- Yahoo & Azure ACS: private
- Facebook: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
- MyOpenID: max-age=86400
- PIP: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
- ADFSv2: no-cache

**Pragma**

- Yahoo, LiveID, Facebook: no-cache
- Google, MyOpenID, Azure ACS value does not exist.

**X-Content-Type-Options:**  [IE8 Details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update), [IE9 Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

- Azure ACS, Google,  : nosniff

**X-XSS-Protection**  [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051632/328397) [More details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie8-security-part-iv-the-xss-filter)

- Facebook, LiveID, ADFSv2 : 0
- Google: 1; mode=block
- Not present in Azure ACS and other providers

**[X-Frame-Options](http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/09/08/x-frame-options/)**  [More Details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options)

- Yahoo: X-Frame-Options: DENY
- Google: SAMEORIGIN

**[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)**  ([How to use with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1653308/328397))

- Google (conditions apply)

**[Strict-Transport-Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5573/396)**  See also [how to disable for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6707978/328397)

- Google (conditions apply)
- PayPal / Lastpass (500 seconds = bit over 8 minutes)
- market.android.com (2592000 seconds = 30 days)

**X-Pad**  // A fix for very very old versions of Netscape

- Verisign PIP

Lastly it's interesting that Facebook has two headers regarding the HTTP Connection
`X-Cnection: close`  and  `Connection: Keep-Alive`.  I'm not sure if they are relevant but I'm including them here for completeness.

Comment: Related: [Preventing Information Disclosure from the browser Back Button / History](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8404/396)

Answer (score 3):

Use HTTPS, cachin/expires won't matter.
X-XSS-Protection as Google does.
Strict-Transport-Security (and the subdomain directive)
nosniff, blame IE.
X-Pad... if someone using using Netscape... there are bigger problems.